# How to bind a data in ng-repeate with different index

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

My json data :

```
var jsondata = [{"credit":"a","debit":[{"credit":"a","amount":1},{"credit":"a","amount":2}]},
 {"credit":"b","debit":[{"credit":"b","amount":3},{"credit":"b""amount":4},{"credit":"b","amount":5}]},
 {"credit":"c","debit":[{"credit":"c","amount":6}]}]
```

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="x in ?????" >  <input>{{ x.amount}}</input></div>
```

Here i want to bind all the (amount) debit value in single grid as input field and if, i tried change input field (amount value) it should reflect in original json. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

my expected output in grid:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.jsondata = [{"credit":"a","debit":[{"credit":"a","amount":1},{"credit":"a","amount":2}]},{"credit":"b","debit":[{"credit":"b","amount":3},{"credit":"b","amount":4},{"credit":"b","amount":5}]},{"credit":"c","debit":[{"credit":"c","amount":6}]}];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
    <div ng-repeat="item in x.debit">
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.amount" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use 2 ng-repeats here.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in jsondata">
    <div ng-repeat = "y in x.debit">
      <div> {{y.amount}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```